# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder076499369/files/nginx.conf: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running following version of docker ce

```
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:      18.09.5
  API version:  1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.8
  Git commit:   e8ff056dbc
  Built:        Thu Apr 11 04:50:00 2019
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Getting following error while building image

> Removing intermediate container 40e7e0172f54
>   ---> 5f2b3358b638 Step 5/10 : COPY files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder076499369/files/nginx.conf: no such
>   file or directory

Re-installing docker. 
Setting up context.

Comment: Add `Dockerfile` pls. Also the folder structure and `build` command.

Comment: I am getting this same error -- I think the Docker client is not sending the build context to the Docker daemon properly, but am not sure why.

Comment: Just check, if nginx.conf is not at the same or below hierarchal level than the docker file

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the following files structure:

```
|-- project
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- files
|   |   |-- nginx.conf
```

Also make sure that next to the Dockerfile you do not have a file ".dockerignore" and if you have one make sure it does not contain an entry for "files" or "nginx.conf".

Then it should work.